# How can I know which button is clicked inside my CardView if I have a dynamic RecyclerView/CardView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have two imageviews with in my card view, now how can I setOnClickListeners so that I can know which button in which cardview is selected. im1 and im2 are my clickable ImageViews

This is my code :

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ConnIfInfo dataModel = ifList.get(position);
    Log.d("Name", "if list name: "+dataModel.getName());
    holder.name.setText(dataModel.getName());
    holder.appName.setText(dataModel.getApp().toString());
    if(String.valueOf(dataModel.getPreferredModeMode().toString()) .equals( String.valueOf(ProjectionTypes.OperationMode.AOA_AA)))
    {
        holder.im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.auto1);
        holder.im2.setImageResource(R.drawable.carlife);
        holder.im1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    iPhoneProjectionManager.startApp(1,"Nexus 5");
                }  catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        holder.im2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    iPhoneProjectionManager.startApp(2,"Nexus 6");
                }  catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

    }

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ifList.size();
}
```

Comment: so whats the issue with above code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the tag to the view. The tag can be any object.

```
holder.im2.setTag(position);
```

you can set many tags also, with the key, and the key should be unique resId. you can dump the ids in ids.xml. Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/samples/BatchStepSensor/res/values/ids.html)

```
holder.im2.setTag(<res_id>, position);
```

and you can get the tag as

```
holder.im2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           v.getTag()
           //or if you set with key then
           v.getTag(<res_id>)
           // please check for null value
        }
    });
```

instead of setting the onClickListener inside the onBindViewHolder you can do that in ViewHolder class itself

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by using Interface also
For more details please check out [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568927/how-to-take-textview-data-from-recycler-view-to-another-activity/44569191#44569191) contains the brief about the how to handle click event by using interface.